# mask not showing completely when rendering

Tags: masking

I have created and animated a mask to add to a video clip in the compositor.
This is frame 147, looks as expected. The cropped image on the foreground and the window on the background.
[image]

The problem is in the next frame (148). It look like this
[image]

As you can see, it shows only a part of the window.

So, there is 179 frames in the video but one frame has a problem with the mask. It doesn't render completely.
I have deleted all the other masks in case is there a hidden duplicate but still no solution.

Please somebody help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution but if somebody knows how to fix it definitely would be awesome.

I copied the splines of the frame 147, created a new mask and paste to render frame 148 and it works.

Once the mask is created go on the node compositer and change the name of the previos mask for the new one. As it is copied for the previous frame you may need to do minimal position changes.
[image]

It doesn't work by just changing the mask. It is necesary to unplug the mask node, change the name of the mask and then plug it again.
[image]

Save the rendered image as a PNG file, separated from the rest and add it later to the image sequence to create the video clip.